# How to trigger a program at shutdown

Tags: login, shutdown

How to trigger a program when shutdown occurs and trigger the another program when login occurs in Ubuntu

Comment: Have You tried such [solution](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run in shutdown you should add your script file into `/etc/rc6.d/`. If you want to run the things in reboot you should add you script file to `/etc/rc0.d/`.

Make sure at the first of your script file name should be K99. After creating your script file run `chmod +x K99Something` to give neccessary permission.